# Using ?: how can I prevent item being store in collection if condition fails? I don't want to store null

Tags: c#

Is there a way to prevent an item being stored in collection if condition fails. In this example I store null but it still counts as a collection item and can be enumerated. In collection I want to have only values from failed checks and no null values.

```
if (part.IsFailure || customer.IsFailure || provider.IsFailure)
{
  return BadRequest(new InvalidArgumentDetails(new List<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail>()
  {
    part.IsFailure ? new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(part.Id), part1.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), part.Error.Message, null) : null,
    customer.IsFailure ? new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(customer.Id), customer.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), customer.Error.Message, null) : null,
    provider.IsFailure ? new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(provider.Id), provider.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), provider.Error.Message, null) : null,
  }));
}
```

Comment: Just create list before if, split if into three (one for each failure) and fill list accordingly and than when list is not empty return bad request. What you have for me has bad readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to put everything on one line of code.  You can conditionally add elements to the list by using `if` statements.  For example:

```
var result = new List<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail>();
if (part.IsFailure)
    result.Add(new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(part.Id), part1.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), part.Error.Message, null));
if (customer.IsFailure)
    result.Add(new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(customer.Id), customer.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), customer.Error.Message, null));
if (provider.IsFailure)
    result.Add(new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(provider.Id), provider.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), provider.Error.Message, null));
if (result.Any())
    return BadRequest(new InvalidArgumentDetails(result));
```

---

Alternatively, if you *want* to build the list with `null` elements (which your quick edit and your recent comment imply) then you can simply filter those elements out afterward:

```
if (part.IsFailure || customer.IsFailure || provider.IsFailure)
{
  return BadRequest(new InvalidArgumentDetails(new List<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail>()
  {
    // your existing conditions to add three elements
  }.Where(x => x != null)));
}   // ^--- filter out null elements here
```

Any way you look at it, you only have two options:

1. Don't add `null` elements to the list.
2. Add `null` elements to the list and then remove them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I want to use ?: operator. I know that it is complexity for complexity's sake.

Comment: @SimasVe: I've updated the answer with another option.  If for whatever reason you want to keep your existing code and continue to add `null` elements to the list, you can just remove them *from* the list before using it.

Comment: Thank you. Now I really see what options I have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nature of `IEnumerable` extensions to conditionally add things like so:

```csharp
var myCollection = Enumerable.Empty<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail>();

myCollection = part.IsFailure
  ? myCollection.Add(new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(part.Id), part1.Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), part.Error.Message, null)
  : myCollection
```

Since the `IEnumerable.Add` method returns the modified `IEnumerable` back to you.

However, if you are wanting to keep the braces like in your example (i.e., `new List<T>() { itemToAdd }`), then I'm afraid that isn't possible, since the braces are really a [wrapper around the `Add` method of `IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). If you really wanted your syntax to stay, then you would have to add a `.Where(x => x != null)` call to the end of your collection. Keep in mind that this will convert your collection to an `IEnumerable`, but since you're returning it to `BadRequest` you should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ICanFail
{
    public bool IsFailure { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }
    
}

public class CanFail: ICanFail
{
    public bool IsFailure { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    public InvalidArgumentFieldDetail GetInvalidArg()
    {
        var res = new InvalidArgumentFieldDetail(nameof(Id), Error.ErrorCode.ToString(), Error.Message, null);
        return res;
    }
}

public class Part: CanFail
{
    //your class
}

public class Customer: CanFail
{
    //your class
}

public class Provider: CanFail
{
    //your class
}


public static class Checker
{

    public static void ExampleRun()
    {
        Part part = new Part();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Provider provider = new Provider();

        BadRequest? returnValue = CheckFail<CanFail>(part, customer, provider);
        if (returnValue is not null)
        {
            //do what you have to do
        }
    }


    public static BadRequest? CheckFail<T>(params T[] cans) where T : CanFail
    {
        
        if (cans.Any(c => c.IsFailure))
        {
            List<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail> detail = new List<InvalidArgumentFieldDetail>();
            foreach (T canFail in cans.Where(c => c.IsFailure))
            {
                detail.Add(canFail.GetInvalidArg());
            }
            return new BadRequest(new InvalidArgumentFieldDetails(detail));
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

You will probably not need the interface, but i added it just in case you might wanna switch to that